# FileNotFoundException - reading csv file

Tags: android, file, csv, import

I´m writing on a quite simple Android app but I can´t find the error in my code. Here is my code that I can import data from a csv file:

```
 public String[] csvread() throws IOException {

        String aktzeile;
        String zeilen[] = new String[200];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fragenbronze.csv"));
        while((aktzeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
            zeilen = aktzeile.split(",");
        }
     return zeilen;
    }
```

The csv file "fragenbronze.csv" is is located at `app - build - intermediates - assets`

Is the assets folder the wrong folder? Google tells me that I should place it there.

Answer (score 2):

To access the asset folder, use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Example:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open("fragenbronze.csv");
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
```